# same warning multiple times when package in @ISA is not loaded

Tags: perl, perl-module

while refactoring some of my perl code i
noticed the following strang behaviour.
consider this small sample script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

package test;
use strict;
my $obj = bless( {}, __PACKAGE__);
our @ISA = qw( missing );

exit(0)
```

the *expected* warning

```
Can't locate package missing for @test::ISA at test.pl line 8
```

appears three times instead of only one time. what are the other two triggers for this warning? all three refer to `exit(0)`.
perl-version 5.12.4 on gentoo linux.

thanks.

Comment: @missing::ISA, &missing::DESTROY are two likely candidates.  Perhaps even &missing::AUTOLOAD...

Comment: There are three warnings only until perl 5.16. With perl 5.18 there are just two warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I believe tjd got the answer.  If you add a DESTROY() and AUTOLOAD() method to the test package, you will get only one warning (about the absence of @test::ISA).

```
   package test;
   use strict;

   sub DESTROY {}
   sub AUTOLOAD {}
```

You generally need to make sure that the packages listed in the @ISA list have already been loaded.  In your example, you might have expected to see something like:

```
   package test;  
   use strict;
   use missing;

   our @ISA = ('missing');
```

It is a bit curious that your package doesn't have an explicit new() method.  Instead, you have a statement that calls bless();

If you had a new() method, like this:

```
   sub new() { return bless {}, __PACKAGE__; }
```

Then you would not see the triple error message until something called new();

```
   package main;
   my $object = test->new(); # Triple warning
```

You might want to use the pragma 'base', which will give you a fatal error saying that it cannot load the 'missing' package:

```
   package test; 
   use strict;
   use base ('missing');

   sub new { bless {}, __PACKAGE__);
```

The base pragma attempts to load the missing package for you.  You do not need a separate 'use  missing' statement.

So the final thing might look like this:

```
   package test;
   use strict;
   use warning;
   use base ('missing');

   sub new { bless {}, __PACKAGE__);
   sub DESTROY {}
   sub AUTOLOAD {}
   1;
```

You could then wrap this all into a file called test.pm and use it in a script:

```
   use strict;
   use test;

   my $object = test->new(); # Should fatal, as there is no 'missing' module
```

Hope this helps.